# How to to automatically adjust the frames for a given font size and slide size in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, presentations, handout, frame

I have a handout in latex (a mixture of text, tables and images). I want to convert it into presentation The problem is that whenever I put frames, I have to compile the document every time to see whether the data fits into that frame or it is exceeding. The font size and slide size is fixed. I want that latex automatically starts a new frame when the data exceed the previous frame. Is there any way out?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to adjust the font size or image size? On the other hand, your audience might be happier with less content and a reasonable font size.

Comment: What kind of contents do you want to present? Is it text, numbers, tables,...? What kind of behaviour do you expect and what exactly does "automatically adjust the frames" mean in this context? Probably a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help clarify?

Comment: From your description, I guess you could be interested in the `allowframebreaks` options. However, please keep in mind, that the `beamer` manual explicitly warns: "Do not use the option `allowframebreaks` except for long bibliographies." and "The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide.  Using the `allowframebreaks` option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation."

Comment: @leandriis  Actually I have a handout in latex (a mixture of text, tables and images). I want to convert it into presentation  The problem is that whenever I put frames, I have to compile the document to see whether the data fits into that frame or it is exceeding. The font size and slide size is fixed. I want that latex automatically starts a new frame when the data exceed the previous frame. Is there any way out?

Comment: @aslam: You could take a look at `allowframebreaks`, als already mentioned in my previous comment. However, please be warned, that this will most likely not result in a well prepared set of slides. You would most definitely be able to achieve a better result if you took our time and carefully prepared each slide. (Keep your audience in mind.)